# How to get the User Birthday date from Slack for integration

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands

I am trying to integrate with Slack where i am using `https://slack.com/api/users.list` which is pulling all the user details but i unable to see the Birthday date. Can anyone please help me how to get the user birthday date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The birthday of a user is not a standard field in Slack. That is why you do not get it from `users.list`.

If you want to work with birthday's you have two options:

1. You can add it as custom field to users with [users.profile.set](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.profile.set) (only on paid teams).
2. Or you can run your own birthday day storage (e.g. the Slack app having its own database) for your bot (which is what most birthday bots do).

Comment: How can we run own birthday date storage. Can you help on this

Comment: Most Slack app will run their own database as main storage. The details depend on many factors, e.g. how your are hosting the Slack app. e.g if your Slack app is running on [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com) than you would most likely use a PostgreSQL database.

Comment: Erik, I am just doing integration with Slack so i dont have much idea or information on Slack. We are planning to automate the process of Birthday wishes on Slack. For this we thought of pulling users list and send a message whose birthday is on the same day. Can you please suggest what will be the best way to do this ?

Comment: You need to build a Slack app, which is basically a web service running on a web server. You can use any platform or language to build it. So the "best way" really depends on what language you can use and options you prefer for hosting your app. See this for an intro on Slack apps: https://api.slack.com/start/overview

Comment: In any case make sure to use one of the standard libraries to access the Slack API, e.g. [this](https://github.com/slackapi/node-slack-sdk) for node-.js or [this](https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient) for Python

Comment: Erik,I already created an App and 1 bot user. Using Javascript i try to pull the User lists thats where i am stuck

Comment: Again, you can not get the birthday info from Slack. You have to get that info from another source and store and retrieve it in your own app, e.g. by adding a database. Or you can just use a big JSON file with all the birthdays that you app as access to.

Comment: e.g. you could send a message to every user asking him to provide your app with the information. then store it and use that later for the birthday information. Or collect the whole list of birthdays from another source, e.g. HR if you are at a company

Comment: You mean to say it is impossible to get the Birthday Date which is available in the profile of Slack ???

Comment: What you suggest is we need to get the users access  from slack and we need to get the birthday dates from any other system then we need to match and send the date to Slack

Comment: No, I am saying the there is no birthday date in the user profile on Slack. Unless it has been added as custom field.